Issue with Button's Background Color Remaining After Navigation in .NET MAUI (iOS 18)
I'm using a contentview with TouchBehavior from the .NET MAUI Community Toolkit, and I have the following code to change the background color and scale when the contentview is pressed:
<ContentView.Behaviors>
    <toolkit:TouchBehavior
        DefaultAnimationDuration="100"
        DefaultAnimationEasing="{x:Static Easing.CubicInOut}"
        PressedOpacity="0.6"
        Command="{Binding Command, Source={x:Reference RowIconLabelElement}, Mode=TwoWay}"
        PressedBackgroundColor="{StaticResource neutralGrayLighter}"
        PressedScale="1.05"
    />
</ContentView.Behaviors>

The behavior works as expected when the button is pressed, and it navigates to another page. However, when I navigate back to the page, the background color sometimes stays as neutralGrayLighter.This issue happens intermittently, about 6 out of 10 navigations. Additionally, I started experiencing this problem after upgrading to iOS 18. Before the update, everything worked correctly.
Has anyone encountered this issue, and how can I ensure that the background color resets properly when navigating back to the page?

Just wait for your bug report to get handled.
